# How to achieve physical implementation of a CNOT gate between spin and energy degrees of freedom of an atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I'm working on a project where I'm considering a two-level system ("atom" for convenience) which possesses two linearly independent degrees of freedom, one of them a spin degree of freedom with in Hilbert space $\{|\uparrow\rangle,~|\downarrow\rangle\}$ and the other an energy degree of freedom in Hilbert space $\{|g\rangle,~|e\rangle\}$. One of the operations I'd like to be able to implement is a CNOT gate between these degrees of freedom with the energy DoF as control qubit and the spin DoF as target qubit. I'm having a bit of a hard time determining a viable physical scheme that could implement such a gate on the "pulse level", although I'm convinced that there is one.

It seems to me that the application of a magnetic field to the atom where we prepare the system such that $\mathbf{\mu}\cdot\mathbf{B}=|E_e-E_g|$ followed by a $\pi$-rotation pulse in the spin basis might be on the right track but I'm genuinely very lost beyond that ill-formed idea.

Has any work been done on this topic and would anyone have any ideas that might help?

EDIT: If it matters, the specific CNOT gate I want is $(|\uparrow\rangle\langle{\downarrow}|+|\downarrow\rangle\langle{\uparrow}|)\otimes|g\rangle\langle{g}|+\hat{\mathbb{I}}\otimes|e\rangle\langle{e}|$

(Copied from the [same question in Quantum Computing Stack Exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/32771/24904)

Comment: This depends strongly on the physics of your two-level system. I can write down any unitary that I want, but that doesn't mean I can find a corresponding interaction that actually occurs in nature

Comment: Do your spin degrees of freedom not contribute to energy? Or can they be nondegenerate, with a large energy contribution from the "energy degree of freedom" and a small splitting from the spin degree of freedom? Like Zeeman splitting of $S_{1/2}$ and $P_{1/2}$ sublevels of a hydrogen electron?

Comment: I don't know about the work done before, but for real atoms I see lots of interactions which can help implementing your gate. For example, if the atom is subjected to a magnetic field, and the Zeeman splitting is different for two electronic orbitals, it allows to act selectively on one of the electronic orbitals. This is very close to CNOT. Another possibility is Raman transitions, because Raman transition amplitudes can be very different for different electronic orbitals.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic for the purposes of what I'm working on, I would like for the spin states to be degenerate in the absence of gates/pulses/applied fields. However, I expect that the "correct" answer as to how to implement the CNOT gate will involve introducing a nondegeneracy just like you're talking about.

Comment: @E.Anikin I didn't consider the idea that the $|e\rangle$ and $|g\rangle$ eigenstates would correspond to a different pattern of Zeeman splittings. Effectively what happens is that two non-degenerate energy eigenstates become four eigenstates due to Zeeman splitting? Do you have any more information as to how a spin-flip pulse might act differently on the different Zeeman levels?

Comment: You will have to specify the details of the hardware you consider, or the Hamiltonian you are in disposal of. "Some" two-level system does not allow for the specific answer. For instance, it is highly relevant what |e> and |g> are.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch you're right. Instead of speaking in purely general terms we can say that the two-level system just *is* some atom or molecule which possesses half integer spin and anharmonic energy levels corresponding to electron orbitals. Let $|e\rangle$ and $|g\rangle$ be the first two of these levels with energy difference $|E_e-E_g|\equiv\hbar\omega_a$.

Comment: So the levels differ by principal quantum numbers? What about the other quantum numbers -- are we allowed to use all those states to implement the gate? And can we excite further electrons? And the spin is the actual spin of the atom? -- I think what you ask is far to unspecific, I would recommend to first read up how such things are implemented in ions or atoms, and see if this is along the lines you want.